# Property of Subordinate Matrix Norm: $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I do not understand why the following property for Matrix subordinate norms holds:
\begin{equation}
\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|
\end{equation}

Please explain clearly as I know that it should be shown by the definition:
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = \sup\{\|A\|: u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|u\|=1\}
\end{equation}

And the fact that:
\begin{equation}
\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|
\end{equation}

I understand the definition and I understand the property. I just can't seem to put them together correctly.

Hints only please!

**EDIT** Is the following reasoning correct:

Let $u$ be any unit vector:
\begin{align}
\|ABu\| \leq& \dfrac{\|ABx\|}{\|x\|}\\
        \leq& \frac{\|A\|\|Bx\|}{\|x\|} \quad{\text{as $Bx$ is a vector}}\\
        \leq& \frac{\|A\|\|B\|\|x\|}{\|x\|} \quad{\text{from above property}}\\
        \leq& \|A\|\|B\|
\end{align}

Since $u$ is any unit vector then we have:
\begin{equation}
\|A\|\|B\| \geq \|AB\|
\end{equation}

Comment: Should your central line be $\|A\| = \sup\{\|Au\| : u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|u\| = 1\}$?

Comment: I changed a bunch of instances of things like $||A||||Bx||$ to things like $\|A\|\|Bx\|$.  This is a nice example of why the latter is standard usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note, the answer below was given in response to the original form of this question which did not contain the line "Hints only please!" or the edit which follows it.*

---

Note that for $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|u\| = 1$, we have $$\|ABu\| = \|A(Bu)\| \leq \|A\|\|Bu\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|\|u\| = \|A\|\|B\|$$ so $\|AB\| = \sup\{\|ABu\| : u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|u\| = 1\} \leq \|A\|\|B\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. Although I didn't see the need of writing the unit vector $u$ as $u=\frac{x}{\| x\|}$. The same conclusion can be reached by applying the same trick to $u$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Please: Don't write \vert\vert A\vert\vert\vert\vert Bx\vert\vert.  Write \|A\|\|Bx\|.  Notice the difference: $\vert\vert A\vert\vert\vert\vert Bx\vert\vert$ versus $\|A\|\|Bx\|$.